how to run a prisma migration in existing database without getting all the database in schema.prisma
I have a migration to create a table in an already existing database, however I can not run the migration with
npx prisma migrate dev
or
npx prisma migrate deploy
I am getting this error:

Drift detected: Your database schema is not in sync with your migration history.

I tried to run npx prisma db pull, but it attempts to modify my schema.prisma file getting all the structure of my database, I don't want that because even after doing this I can not run the migration due some error of another tables in the generated scheme.prisma)
so, I just want to run a simple migration to create a table in my already existing database, without reseting it or getting all the database structure into the prisma project
I already tried using these commands:
npx prisma migrate dev 
npx prisma migrate deploy
npx prisma migrate dev --create-only
npx prisma db pull
npx prisma migrate dev --name introspected_change
npx prisma migrate dev --name 20221010132059_first_migrate


but nothing works to run a simple migration in my database
